# Canonical class & ring of projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$ in differential geometry

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, projective-geometry, curvature

David Mumford remarks in his book Algebraic Geometry I, Complex Projective Varieties on
page 109 that the fact that the canonical ring $\oplus_{k=0}^{\infty} \Omega_{k, \mathbb{P}^n}$
of projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$ has a very poor structure ($\Omega_{k, \mathbb{P}^n}=0$
for all $k \ge 1$) is *closely related* to the fact from differential-geometry that
$\mathbb{P}^n$ 'stands at one end of the curvature spectrum having the most positive
curvature of any algebraic variety'.

Moreover it is also stated that for a smooth variety the canonical class $K_{\mathbb{P}^n}$
turns out to represent minus the cohomology class of the Ricci curvature of $X$
(source Cornalba-Griffiths: Algebraic Geometry Arcata 1974 AMS).

Unfortunately my basic knowledge of differential geometry is not sufficient to
understand the meaning of these two remarks. At first, what does it mean that
a smooth variety or say a manifold has the most positive curvature? In case of surfaces the
[Gaussian curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature) associates to every point on the surface a real number and therefore
it is natural to compare the curvatures of surfaces by the relation "$\le$" and it's reasonable to call one curvature
'more positive than the other' or vice versa. On the other hand if we deal with manifolds
of dimension $n >2$ then the curvature (presumbly Mumford means here the [Riemann curvature tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature_of_Riemannian_manifolds#The_Riemann_curvature_tensor) ) the curvature is not a number any more, so that's incomprehensible
to me how in higher dimensions one can call a curvature 'most positive'. Any idea
what Mumford here wants to say.

The second point is how generally for divisor $D$ on manifold $M$ or say it's associated
bundle $L(D) \to M$ one can associate a certain cohomology class in the way Mumford here did in order to compare it with the class associated to Ricci curvature? As 1st Chern class of $L(D)$?

Comment: I imagine he's referring to sectional curvature. I agree his phrasing doesn't quite make sense, especially since you can 'scale up' a metric to get e.g. a large sphere with small sec curvature. Perhaps one way of formalizing his statement is the 1/4-pinched sphere theorem: any manifold with sec curvature in $(1/4,1]$ is diffeomorphic to a sphere, and $P^n$ with FS metric has sec curvature in $[1/4,1]$, so it has sec curvature "as close as possible" to a sphere (e.g. if you bound curvature above, it has highest min curvature).

Comment: I can't say with certainty what Mumford meant but in my opinion, it's probably related to the fact that "any compact Kaehler manifold with positive holomorphic bisectional curvature is biholomorphic to complex projective space", see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2094604/84942 For the second question, one way to associate a Chern class to a line bundle is to take a connection and look at the curvature of the connection (Chern-Weil theory).